# When we click on edit address, It is showing subfields under that address field. How to achieve this?

Tags: apex

When we click on edit address, It is showing subfields under that address field. How to achieve this?[image]

Comment: Please elaborate. This is standard Salesforce behavior, you don't have to do anything to achieve this. Why is your question labeled with "apex"?

Comment: I've downvoted because I saw a similar question to this (which I commented on or answered) which appears to have been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Standards Address fields are compound fields in Salesforce. which means they have many sub-fields which together form the compound address field. Reference : [Address field reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm)

Unfortunately we can't create custom (compound) fields using the "Address" datatype yet, this requirement is still in an Idea phase and salesforce is working on its development. Reference : [Idea for the requirement](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrVWAA0)

For now, You have to create separate fields for the Street, City, State, Country, and Postal Code.  Also, you can't use the State/Country picklists as Value Sets on your custom State picklist field.